# XErrorEvent structure field meaning

Tags: c, xlib

I'm currently having some issues with Xlib and CEF and I need to investigate the `XErrorEvent` that is sent to the function registered with `XSetErrorHandler`.

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    Display *display;   /* Display the event was read from */
    XID resourceid;     /* resource id */
    unsigned long serial;   /* serial number of failed request */
    unsigned char error_code;   /* error code of failed request */
    unsigned char request_code; /* Major op-code of failed request */
    unsigned char minor_code;   /* Minor op-code of failed request */
} XErrorEvent;
```

I would like to know the meaning of the `type`, `request_code`, and `minor_code` fields. [There is a book on C language interface for the X window system](https://www.x.org/docs/X11/xlib.pdf) but I couldn't find anything about this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is what identifies a typeless memory pointer as pointer to an XErrorEvent - its value is always `X_Error`.

`request_code` is [a protocol request of the procedure that failed, as defined in X11/Xproto.h](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/default-handlers.html), basically what kind of request generated the error (line 2020 and forward):

```
/* Request codes */

#define X_CreateWindow                  1  
#define X_ChangeWindowAttributes        2   
#define X_GetWindowAttributes           3   
#define X_DestroyWindow                 4
#define X_DestroySubwindows             5   
#define X_ChangeSaveSet                 6
#define X_ReparentWindow                7
#define X_MapWindow                     8
...
```

`minor_code` is similar to `request_code` except being used by extensions. Each extension gets its own `request_code` in the range 128-255. The `minor_code` identifies a particular request defined by that extension. So, X11 support up to 127 extensions, and each extension may define up to 255 requests. [The exact paragraph:](https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Protocol/OpCodes/)

> Each extension is assigned a single opcode from that range, also known
>   as it's “major opcode.” For each operation provided by that extension,
>   typically a second byte is used as a “minor opcode.” Minor opcodes for
>   each extension are defined by the extension.

Comment: Thanks! I had found a part of the answer in the meantime. I was wondering why I was getting request code above 127. Where can I find more info about the extensions?

Comment: @nm_tp [XListExtensions and XQueryExtension](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XQueryExtension.3.html) can be used to find out what extensions exist on your system and what request code it has been designated. Minor codes are defined by the extension implementation, e.g. [libX11](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/blob/master/src/XErrorDB) where I would assume "XProtoError.RENDER.4: RenderBadGlyph" means "minor code 4 for the RENDER extension means RenderBadGlyph error". But as I said, implementation detail. Easiest is just to roll with the builtin error messages.

Comment: I would roll with the builtin messages but it is not I who wrote the code. Thans once again and this is the accepted answer!